# 'n. def.' column - how to check that the number is defined

Tags: teradata

I have a FLOAT column Teradata for which, as number of rows appears as `'n. def.'`
`'n. def.'` has been populated corresponding to numpy 'nan'.

I am trying to catch those `'n. def.'` values.

- Checking for `NULL` does not work.
- `SEL * where mycol BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0` did not filter out the `n. def.`'s (having set here a range of acceptable values)
- Found an ugly hack: `CAST (col_1 AS CHAR(200)) AS col_1_str` returns `**********************`

Comment: How did you get `NaN` into that column?

Comment: I have a numpy `nan` which has been injected there with `pyodbc`

Comment: Based on your hack, try `TO_NUMBER(TRIM(col_1))`which should return NULL

Comment: OK, yes, that works as well. Unless there's a neater way...